# RSpec - Can't mock ActiveRecord model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking

Trying to mock an ActiveRecord model class in RSpec unit test. Here I'm summarizing stuff.

**RSpec test**

```
it 'calls create method' do
  response_code = post @url, params: { id: @id }
  expect(response_code).to eql(200)

  allow(MyModel).to receive(:create)

  expect(MyModel).to receive(:create)
end
```

**Controller method**

The controller entry point.

```
def controller_method
  other_model_method
  #...
  render json: #...
end
```

**Other model that calls MyModel**

```
Class OtherModel < ActiveRecord
  #...

  def other_model_method
    MyModel.create(attr: value)
  end
end
```

Running the test I get:

```
(MyModel(id: integer).create(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
```

I'm new to Rails and Ruby. This pair allow(MyModel)/expect(MyModel) I saw in another post but is not working for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Its not clear from the question what you're actually trying to accomplish or what behavior this is actually supposed to test. 'calls create method' is not a behavior - its the implementation. `allow(MyModel).to receive(:create)` will replace the original method with a mock. `expect(MyModel).to receive(:create)` also stubs the method but it also sets an expectation on that the method should be / have been called. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it's good practice to do your `allow` calls before you trigger the action. You then need to use the past-tense matchers to check for whether your mocks were called.

The advantage of getting into this habit is that you use the same style in your tests where you just need to mock something as when you care about setting expectations against those mocks.

Something like this:

```
it 'calls create method' do
  allow(MyModel).to receive(:create)

  response_code = post @url, params: { id: @id }

  expect(response_code).to eq(200)
  expect(MyModel).to have_received(:create).with(some: value)
end
```

You can replace `some: value` with whatever you expect the mock to have been called with.

If you're doing this in lots of tests in the same spec, you can shift the `allow` calls to a `before` block. Like this:

```
before do
  allow(MyModel).to receive(:create)
end

it 'calls create method' do
  response_code = post @url, params: { id: @id }

  expect(response_code).to eq(200)
  expect(MyModel).to have_received(:create).with(some: value)
end
```

Comment: Setting expectations before or after the code under test is called are both valid options and the choice is really more a matter of style. Setting the expectations after the test rimes better with AAA and GWT.

Answer (score 0):

Your mocking expectations should happen in the test before the code is calling them, so

```
it 'calls create method' do
   expect(MyModel).to receive(:create)

   response_code = post @url, params: { id: @id }
   expect(response_code).to eql(200)
end
```